# Calling JavaScript Function as Function parameter limit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, pug

Currently writing a web app in NodeJS. Lately I've came to nesting(?) function parameters as functions. An example is here, as is written in my pug file:

```
td= ScenarioDifference(ScenarioDifference(ScenarioDifference(ScenarioSales(year), ScenarioSalesCost(year)), ScenarioOverhead(year)), profitLoss) * workbook3.value_multiple
```

I understand that this severely limits readability and cleaness of the code, it is easier to put into variables; however does it affect performance at all, or it doesn't matter to JavaScript, or programming in particular? What would be the limit of such parameter nesting?

Comment: The limit would be when too much nesting causes, uh, a stack overflow, which is very unlikely to occur with manual nesting like that - it's more often caused by problematic recursive logic. Nested function calls *do* have a tiny bit of overhead, but it's almost never something worth worrying about. Code readability matters far more.

Comment: Break it apart. You will appreciate it in the future if you have to modify it and can't remember what is what

Comment: There *is* a parameter limit independent of the stack, but it's very rare you'll ever hit it before a stack overflow unless you're spreading an array (and the only remotely common case for this that you could run into this with is `Array.prototype.push(...values)`).